# Lists of questions sometimes don't show how many answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

Sometimes lists of questions don't indicate how many answers they have received:

[image: No box showing number of answers]

Yes [this particular question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/are-only-80-of-canadians-born-in-the-country/4371#4371) has not only received an answer, that answer has been selected:

[image: Answer, with check mark]

Why doesn't the list show the appropriate information?

And, perhaps related, why does the bottom of the entry say "answered Jun 7 …", when all the other items in the list say "asked …"?

EDIT: I was obviously blind, but even so, I've now made a suggestion for improvement: [For answers, lists of questions and answers should display the position of each answer within its question - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332870/for-answers-lists-of-questions-and-answers-should-display-the-position-of-each).

Comment: That's not a question, it's an answer. You can tell because the question title has an "A" next to it. If you want search to only return questions, you'll want to add the search modifier "is:question".

Comment: @Catija.  D'oh!  The long list was entirely questions except for that one answer, so I saw it as wrong rather than as uncommon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a list of questions. It's a search result and some of the results are questions and others are answers.

[image: Excerpt of screenshot from question showing the question title with an "A:" circled next to it.]

The "A" in this screenshot shows you that this is an answer, not a question. The votes reflect the score of the answer (15). You can also tell that the answer is accepted (kinda) because the "15 votes" is green. If the answer isn't accepted, it's black - but we should really find a better way to indicate this.

If you'd like to search for questions only, you can add the search modifier `is:question` to restrict it, otherwise, search results will default to return both questions and answers.

Comment: For the lazy between us `is:q` suffices, where q is obviously short for question.

Answer (score 1):

The "A: " in the search result means that it is an *answer*, not a question. And obviously, answers don't have answers.

To answer your related question, it says "answered" because, as I said, the search result *is* an answer.